# How do I create Vertical tabBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I create Vertical tabBar in Flutter? Unlike [TabBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) where tabs are displayed in a horizontal row, I want to place them vertically in a Column. [see this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xjJg.jpg)

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was simple. Here what I did. I wrapped the TabBar in a [RotatedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html) after decorating & styling it. And finally, wrapped everything inside [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) and done.

Update on 30 Oct 2021: Use [navigation Rail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html) instead or something else from pub.dev.

Comment: Can you help me out with the sample code? I applied [RotatedBox] (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html) twice. It makes the alignment vertical and the text are horizontal but the issue now is the indicator is still vertical as the second rotated box was applied to child Text only. It's taking huge space in vertical alignment.

Comment: unfortunately, I deleted that code. But it was very easy you don't need to add RotatedBox twice add `quarterTurns` to rotate your position. Mine was totally working fine everything, didn't have huge space.

Comment: No issues. It went smoothly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

For your use case, it would be easier to use [NavigationRail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html) instead of trying to rotate everything.

Comment: When I asked this question at that time there was no Navigation Rail widget. And I was also a newbie, didn't have much knowledge otherwise it's really easy to implement without rotating anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Drawer example in flutter gallery, they have the use case defined, and it provides many samples